# How do smart contract transfer funds if they do not have private keys?

Tags: transactions, contract-invocation, signature

I am reading a book on ethereum and I saw this:

> Only externally owned accounts have a corresponding private key.
> Private keys are used for signing new transactions sent to the network
> as a means of authentication. Smart contracts cannot initiate new
> transactions, so there is need for them to sign any operation.

If smart contracts have no keys, cannot sign transactions, how can they then be used to transfer or move funds? Because i believe moving funds requires a signed transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contracts run in the Ethereum Virtual Machine that has several opcodes that can be used transfer ether `CALL`, `SELFDESTRUCT`, `CREATE`, `CREATE2`. These opcodes allow the contract to transfer funds without a signature.